# Interrupting D3 transition: How to interrupt an ongoing transition upon drag?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following is the small piece of code.

```
timeline_svg.append("line")
.attr("class", "track")
.attr("x1", x.range()[0] + 135 - marginTimeAxis) //
.attr("x2", x.range()[1] + marginTimeAxis)
.attr('y1', 10)
.attr('y2', 10)
.select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
.attr("class", "track-inset")
.select(function() { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
.attr("class", "track-overlay") //axis tAxis
.call(d3.drag()
    .on("start.interrupt", function() { timeline_svg.interrupt();})
    .on("start drag", function() {
    currentValue = d3.event.x;
    console.log("current value:-> ", currentValue);
    update(t.invert(currentValue)); 
    })
);
```

In the above code, whenever I am trying to start a drag action timeline_svg.interrupt() should get called but that is not happening. The transition doesn't getting interrupted. I want the transition of the svg to get interrupted upon drag.

F.Y.I I am using d3v5 for my project.

Tried Approaches:
#1.

```
.call(d3.drag()
.on("interrupt", function() { timeline_svg.interrupt();})
```

2. 

```
.call(d3.drag()
.on("start.interrupt", function() { timeline_svg.transition.duration(0);})
```

Thank you for reading my post I appreciate your time and effort you put into this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `selection.interrupt()` when dragging:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cx",100)
  .attr("cy",100)
  .attr("fill","crimson")
  
circle.transition()
  .attr("cx", 300)
  .attr("fill","steelblue")
  .duration(5000)
  
var drag = d3.drag()
  .on("start", function() {
    d3.select(this).interrupt()
  })
  .on("drag", function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("cx", d3.event.x)
      .attr("cy", d3.event.y)
  })

circle.call(drag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width = 500 height=300></svg>
```

You almost had it between the two approaches.

Your first approach doesn't work for a number of reasons: transition.on() has an event type "interrupt", but d3-drag does not; but no interrupt event will be triggered until you use `selection.interrupt()`, listening for the interrupt to trigger the interrupt is putting the horse before the cart.

Your second approach doesn't work because you aren't setting a new transition: `selection.transition.duration(0)` should be `selection.transition().duration(0);`

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx",50)
  .attr("cy",50)
  .attr("r", 10)
  
circle.transition()
  .attr("cx", 200)
  
circle.transition
  .duration(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried both of your approaches on different charts, they tend to work over there but not in my specific project that I am doing. However if this is not too much to ask, can we connect on a zoom call to figure this out ? because there is lot of animation going on and I cant put everything in one stackoverflow post. Thanks for your attention though.

Comment: If possible it would be ideal to see your code first.